# Angular - Directive hides input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
      scope: {ngModel:'='},
      link: function(scope, element) {          
           element.bind("keyup", function(event) {
                  scope.ngModel=0;
                  scope.$apply();
            });          
      }
  }
});
```

This works as planned, setting the variables to 0 on keyup, but it doesn't reflect the changes on the input themselves.  Also when initialized, the values of the model are not in the input.  Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/prXm3/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a watcher to populate the data since the directive creates an isolated scope.

```
angular.module('test', []).directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function (val) {
                element.val(scope.ngModel);
            });

            element.bind("keyup", function (event) {
                scope.ngModel = 0;
                scope.$apply();
                element.val(0); //set the value in the dom as well.
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Or, you can change the template to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.testModel.inputA" my-directive>
```

the data will be populated thought it will break your logic to do the event binding.

So it is easier to use the watcher instead.

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NuCMr/)**</kbd>

Comment: That does the initial change, but any subsequent changes to the input does not revert the input back to 0.